# How to test if the value of a token is not a specific value

Tags: macros

I have a bunch of tokens with default values. I need to test each of these and print a message in case they are still the default value. I am able to do this manually as shown below. Now when I attempt to write a macro for this I run into problems. I want to be able to report the name of the token that was not set so attempted to pass in the name of the token and use `\the\#1` to get the value.  I am thinking there is someting basic I am missing and have tried a bunch of things but still am not able to make this work. Any ideas?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newtoks{\MyParameter}
\MyParameter={X}         % Set default value

\newcommand{\TestIfGivenValue}[2]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\the\#1}{#2}}{%
\warningbox{B: Please set the value of $backslash$#1}%
}{%
    B: Yes, the \textbackslash MyParameter has a non default value. 
}}


\begin{document}

% Manual method: works great
\ifthenelse{\equal{\the\MyParameter}{X}}{%
    A: Please set the value of \textbackslash MyParameter \\%
}{
    A: Yes, the \textbackslash MyParameter has a non default value. 
}

% Now attempt to wrap this in a new command
\TestIfGivenValue{MyParameter}{X}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TeX has to see names as 'tokens': you can't put `\#1` and expect TeX to turn it into a control sequence. So you should either do

```
\newcommand{\TestIfGivenValue}[2]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\the#1}{#2}}{%
\warningbox{B: Please set the value of \noexpand#1}%
}{%
    %B: Yes, #1 has a non default value. 
}}
```

and use it with the control sequence: `\TestIfGivenValue\myvalue{something}`, or construct the name using `\csname`:

```
\newcommand{\TestIfGivenValue}[2]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\expandafter\the\csname#1\endcsname}{#2}}{%
\warningbox{B: Please set the value of \expandafter\noexpand\csname#1\endcsname}%
}{%
    %B: Yes, #1 has a non default value. 
}}
```

which will work as: `\TestIfGivenValue{myvalue}{something}`.

The `\csname ... \endcsname` construct turns `myvalue` into the *token* `\myvalue`, which is what TeX needs to see for everything to work. I've also used `\expandafter` in the second version of the answer, to make sure that `\the` 'sees' the correct input.

Comment: @Joseph: in fact, the `\expandafter` before `\the` seems unnecessary: I believe that `\the` expands whatever it sees until it cannot anymore. If what remains is a register, then `\the` reads it, otherwise, error.

Comment: This worked great for me. I did have to add \relax at the end or each line, but otherwise excellent solution. Thank You.

Comment: @Peter: Interesting. Please let's see where you put the `\relax'es`. It may have to do with spurious spaces, the need for which isn't apparent in Joseph's solution.

Comment: Oppps. Sorry about that. I did NOT have to adjust the solution above, just when invoking this macro, I had to add a \relax at the end of each call. I do not understand why they were necessary, but after I included that things worked as I needed.

Comment: @Bruno: That's interesting. I didn't find this behaviour of `\the` documented in the TeXbook or in _TeX by Topic_. Do you know any reference?

Comment: @Hendrik: your question made me look into `tex.web`, but i couldn't find anything. It should happen in the `scan_something_internal` procedure, but none of the cases seems to be about macro expansion.

Comment: @Hendrik: I _think_ that the key line is `begin get_x_token; scan_something_internal(tok_val,false);` In other words, "get the next token, expanded, and then scan something internal"

Comment: @Bruno: Ermm ... where do you get "expanded" from? From the "x" in `get_x_token`? Ah I see: "_get\_x\_token_, meaning 'get an expanded token'".

Comment: @Hendrik: search `get_x_token` in `tex.web`. There is also `get_token` (not expanded), and `x_token` (used in weird cases).

Comment: @Bruno: See the 2nd part of my previous comment: I had already found it.